# How to use Kotlin Higher Order Function in nested Recyler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view(**Parent**) and inside it, I have another recycler View (**Child**).

There are 2 operations in **child** recycler View which I want to get on Fragment Class and do some things dynamically.

Architecture: MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for higher order function.

**TextAdapter.kt class**

```
class TextAdapter(
    val onClick: (String) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<TextAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemTextBinding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
    ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(
            ItemTextBinding.inflate(
               LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
               parent,
               false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        val adapter = InnerAdapter {
            onClick.invoke(it)
        }
        binding.recyclerViewList.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerViewList.setData(list)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    fun setData(newList: ArrayList<String>) {
        list.clear()
        list.addAll(newList)
    }
}
```

**Inner adapter**

```
class InnerAdapter(
    val onClick: (String) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemText1Binding) : 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
    ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(
            ItemText1Binding.inflate(
               LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
               parent,
               false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        binding.tvTxt.text = list[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            //change background color
            onClick.invoke(list[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    fun setData(newList: ArrayList<String>) {
        list.clear()
        list.addAll(newList)
    }
}
```

Now you can get the value of the item click on the setAdapter
Let's see how

The below function is called from the fragment class where the adapter is set

```
    val adapter = TextAdapter {
        showToast(it)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can achieve your desired behavior by following these steps:

I will use `Lambda` to refer to `Higher Order Function`.

1. Pass the `Lambda` function from `Activity/Fragment -> Parent Adapter`
2. Pass the `Lambda` function from `Parent Adapter -> Child Adapter`.

**For example**, this code shows how to get a callback from nested Recyclerview when a user clicks `Error Item` from child Recyclerview.

```
//In Activity/Fragment
private var errorClick: () -> Unit 
parentAdapter.setErrorClick(errorClick)

//In Parent Adapter
private var errorClick: () -> Unit 
childAdapter.setErrorClick(errorClick)
 
//In Child Adapter - Now use errorClick to callback methods to Activity/Fragment
private var errorClick: () -> Unit // Use IT!
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.